# Entity framework error with AsNoTracking and ObjectStateManager

Tags: entity-framework

As you can see from the code below i use AsNoTracking to get my object.
I then even use ObjectSateManager to see what is going on and i can see
nothing being tracked in the l* collections and yet i still get

"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key".

Any ideas?

==========================================
        BasketRepository repo = new BasketRepository();

```
            var ba = repo.GetById(8);

            var bpro = new BasketProduct(ba, ba.BasketProducts.First().Product, 3);

            repo.AddToBasket(bpro);
           repo.Save();
```

==================================

```
    public Basket GetById(int basketId)
    {
        // eager-load product info
        var basket = dbContext.Baskets.Include("BasketProducts")
                                      .Include("BasketProducts.Product.Brand").AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == basketId);;
        return basket;
    }
```

======================================

```
  public void AddToBasket(BasketProduct product)
    {
        var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
        ObjectStateManager objectStateManager = ctx.ObjectStateManager;
        var l1 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
        var l2 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
        var l3 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted);
        //var l4 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Detached);
        var l5 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged);

        var existingProductInBasket = dbContext.BasketProducts.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == product.BasketId && b.ProductId == product.ProductId);
        var l6 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
        var l7 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
        var l8 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted);
        //var l4 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Detached);
        var l9 = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged);

        //objectStateManager.
        dbContext.Entry<BasketProduct>(product).State = existingProductInBasket == null ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

    }
```

Comment: The question is: what is the lifespan of `dbContext`? Is it always new when you get to changing the object's state?

Answer (score 1):

When you use asNoTracking() you get an unconnected entity that cannot be updated normally with EntityState.Modified. Then, one trick is to replace the cached entity values with non-cached entity values.

Here is the source code I use for special case where asNoTracking is necessary. It can be

```
private T ReplaceEntity(T cachedEntity, T nonCachedEntity) {

     dbContext.Entry(cachedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(nonCachedEntity);

     return cachedEntity;
}
```

A common use can be:

```
public virtual T FindFirstBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool asNoTracking = false)
{
     if (asNoTracking)
     {
          T cachedEntity = dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
          T nonCachedEntity = dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

          return ReplaceEntity(cachedEntity, nonCachedEntity);
     }
     return dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

For your situation:

```
var cachedEntity = dbContext.BasketProducts.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == product.BasketId && b.ProductId == product.ProductId);
var nonCachedEntity = dbContext.BasketProducts.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(b => b.BasketId == product.BasketId && b.ProductId == product.ProductId);

var product= ReplaceEntity(cachedEntity, nonCachedEntity);
dbContext.Entry<BasketProduct>(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

That was actually by bad. It can be a bit difficult conceptually to get used to the idea of
how things get attached and tracked by EF. The secret is to remember that if you have an object
graph (objects with relationships to other objects) whenever an object of the graph gets attached with a state X then all the other objects in the graph seem to be attached as well in that state.

In my scenario i was quite stupidly using 
var bpro = new BasketProduct(ba, ba.BasketProducts.First().Product, 3);
to create a test product that actually already existed in the database and it was part of the object 
graph containing the basket and its products. When i tried to attach this "new" basket EF rightly complained that an object with the same key already exists in the attached graph!